# Singular or Plural (has/have vs was/were)?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

1) There has been a funeral, two weddings and three thefts since you left.

OR

1) There have been a funeral, two weddings and three thefts since you left.

2) There was a boy and two girls inside the room.

OR

2) There were a boy and two girls inside the room.

3) Two girls and a boy was murdered.

OR

3)Two girls and a boy were murdered.

Comment: (3) needs *were*. For a verb *before* a  list, see the question in my next comment.

Comment: I already knew about 3rd one but still asked to clarify. What about first two though?

Comment: See the answers to the duplicate question. Some native speakers use *have/were*, and some use *has/was* in this kind of sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the solution to your problem, it is necessary to examine the word "there"

"**There**" is only ever an adverb. There is a common misconception that "there" can be a pronoun.

**There** means "at **that** place." (**Here** means "at **this** place" and "**where**" means "at **which** place")[1].

We know that **there** is an adverb because **there** cannot be the subject of the sentence:

**There is** a dog in the garden (A dog is in the garden.)

**There are** two dogs in the garden. (Two dogs are in the garden.)

because, in English, the verb's form is dictated by its subject, the subject cannot be "**there**", the subject must be "dog" and "dogs" respectively.

The inversion of subject and verb is relatively common when a sentence is fronted by an adjunct:

*Only after the war was over* **did he go** home

*Dearly* **do I love** you.

*Many* **are the times** that I thought of you. (Many **are the times**  -> The times exist numerously.)

This explains the apparently irregular position of the verb

**There** may be

(i) *weakly* demonstrative and merely indicates the existence of an item -> “**There** is a dog in the garden.” Or “**There** are lions in Africa” This is because the only way that the verb “to be” can take an adverb is in its meaning of “to exist”[2].

(ii)    *clearly* demonstrative when used with a non-stative/dynamic verb: "Look **there**!"

It might seem that **there** can be a noun/pronoun meaning “that place [over there]” e.g. “He left **there** last night.” This occurs only because the other forms - *thence* and *thither* - which indicate motion have been all but lost and “he left **there** last night”  = He left **from that place** last night, in which “from that place” is adverbial and has the meaning of “thence[sup]1[/sup]”.

The question then arises of what the subject is in the example sentences:

1) There have been a funeral since you left, as well as two weddings and three thefts.

This can be understood as

(i) a funeral **has taken place**, and also two weddings and three thefts since you left.

(ii)    a funeral, two weddings and three thefts **have taken place** since you left. (This is and extended meaning 4 of “to be” at [2]

2) There was a boy and two girls inside the room.

Likewise:

(i) A boy was in the room as well as two girls.

(ii)    A boy and two girls were inside the room.

[1] There, here, and where also may substitute for thence, thither and hence, hither, and whence, whither.

[2] In Old English, there were three (maybe four) “to be” verbs: 
1.  the verb (sind/sindon and sie) which gave us “am, is, art, and are” (sind and sie) “I am John.”

2. the verb (beon/buan) that gave us “be and being”: this verb meant to become or to grow. “He is tall.”
3. the verb (wasan) that gave us was/were. This verb had the sense ‘to remain, to stay (the night) “I was in Paris,” and thus to exist, i.e. be present, (in a place or state) “There is a dog in the garden.”
4. (There is a fourth verb “earan” which has the meaning of “to create or come into existence”, but this is not conclusively connected to any of the current forms of “to be”.)

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/there-is.3629911/#post-18496185

Further information can be obtained from the OED (behind a paywall)

> There (adv.)
>
> 4. Used unemphatically to introduce **a sentence or clause in which, for the sake of emphasis or preparing the hearer, the verb comes before its subject**, as “there comes a time when, etc.”, “there was heard a rumbling noise.”
>
> In interrogative sentences **there** comes between the verb and subject, as “*Breathes there the man, etc.?*”, or follows the first word of a compound verb, as “*Does there breathe a man?*”, “*Shall there be any notice taken of it?*”
>
> The same order was formerly observed after an introductory adv. or clause, as “*Then came there a voice, Soon shall there arise a prophet.*”
>
> **Grammatically, there is no difference between “There comes the train!” and “There comes a time when, etc.**”; but, while in the former there is demonstrative and stressed, in the latter it has been reduced to a mere anticipative element occupying the place of the subject which comes later.
>
> Preceding or following a main verb, or following any verb, there, thus used, is stressless (proclitic or enclitic: e.g. there-ˈcame, ˈbreathes-there, ˈis-there, ˈwill-there), but preceding be or an auxiliary, there has a slight stress, and the verb is enclitic (e.g. ˈthere-is, ˈthere-was, ˈthere-will).
>
> a. with intransitive verbs.
>
> c888   Ælfred tr. Boethius De Consol. Philos. iii. §1   **Þa** com þær gan in to me heofencund Wisdom.
>
> 1857   H. T. Buckle Hist. Civilisation Eng. I. vii. 399   From all these things **there** resulted consequences of vast importance.
>
> c. with a verb in the passive voice.
>
> 1912   N.E.D. at There   Mod. Here, *there* were found various relics of Franklin's expedition.
>
> **d. especially with the verb to be: cf. be v. 1b, 4b there is, there are, are equivalent to French il est, il y a, German es ist, es sind, es gibt, Spanish hay. (For such phrases as there is no saying = ‘it is impossible to say’, see no adj. 4.)**
>
> c893   tr. Orosius Hist. i. i. §22   *Þær* is mid Estum an mægð.
>
> 1823   F. Clissold Narr. Ascent Mont Blanc 22   *There* being no moon.
>
> **e. When a relative clause follows, the relative pron. (that, who, or which) is often omitted. Now chiefly colloquial or archaic, as in ballad style.** Cf. that pron.2
>
> ?a1366   Romaunt Rose 1239   *Ther is no cloth sitteth bet On damiselle, than doth roket.*
>
> 1912   N.E.D. at There   Mod. colloq. *There's a man at the door wants to see you*.
>
> **5. a. At that point or stage in action, proceeding, speech, or thought; formerly sometimes referring to what immediately precedes or follows: at that juncture; on that; on that occasion; then. **
>
> a1400   Relig. Pieces fr. Thornton MS. 77   *At myn endynge..I pray þe lady helpe me *þare.**
>
> 1706   G. Farquhar Recruiting Officer i. i. 2   *Brother! Hold there Friend, I'm no Kindred to you that I know of, as yet.*